# Sed to change a derby jdbc connection ins a file

Tags: sed

This should be pretty straight forward but its driving me nuts. 
I need to change a derby db connection in a file, all I want to change is the hostname its connect

```
jdbc:derby://myhostname.com:1527/myContextRoot;
```

I am not sure what the hostname will be so need to wildcard it, the rest of the 
format will always be the same.  So just change the text between `//` and `:1527`.

Comment: Actually the full line would be 
connect 'jdbc:derby://myhostname.com:1527/myContextRoot;';

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like this:

```
sed s_//.*:1527_//\*:1527_g test.txt
```

Uses the `_` delimiter to avoid messing with the `/`s. Matches characters between `//` and `:1527` (inclusive), then substitutes with those same characters and the literal `*`.

Comment: You don't need to escape the second asterisk in that line, because it's in a *replacement string*, and not part of a regexp that is being matched.

Comment: Thanks!
I had this worked out
sed s"/jdbc:derby:\/\/.*:1527/jdbc:derby:\/\/$NEWHOST:1527/"

Answer (score 0):

The shortest solution I can think of for this would be:

```
sed -e 's=//[^:]*=//*=' ...
```

Like Mica's answer, this uses an alternate delimiter, and assumes the hostname ends at the first colon.  This leaves your port in place rather than matching against it and replacing it with itself.